# Post request to JSON server through FETCH api refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, post, fetch-api, json-server

I am trying to send POST requests through fetch API to JSON-server. Function is called on a simple button click (type 'button', not 'submit'). When I replace POST request with GET request everything works like it supposed to, but with POST I have a problem. Request passes, on the JSON-server entity gets created but keeps refreshing the page after each request. Also, I don't have a response from JSON-server, google chrome says 'Failed to load response data'. 
Where I'm making a mistake?

```
  const comment = {
      text: "test comment",
      article_id: 3
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(comment));
    const options = {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(comment)
    }
    fetch(`${URL_COMMENTS}`, options)
        .then(response => { return response.json() })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        });
```

Comment: Do you get any other errors in console? Something CORS-related maybe? (Make sure to use the “preserve log” option, so that reloading the current document does not clear it of previous errors.)

Comment: I don't have any errors in the console and I use "preserve log" option. Everything seems to be working fine, no errors and data is created on JSON-server. It just keeps reloading page. Also, button is created dynamically, but I set type to be 'button'.

Comment: Try to change the `body` attribute from `options` to `data`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Live Server extension, try disabling that and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out for Json sever port number running on your machine

attach the html form code
So we can try it on oru local machine to reproduce the issue.... Which help us to resolve the issue easy